# converting to convert a string to double with limitation

Tags: c++

I'm using c++ and I'm trying to convert a string to double, the string is given to me as an input in the form: "xx.yy", and it should stay that way, meaning no more than two digits after the dot.
I've tried atof and strod but outcome was no good, plus i can't use anything to spectacular' because it's for a course and no one will belive me

```
            str_db  = strtod(ptr, NULL);
            item->price = str_db;
```

str_db is type double.
Thank you.

Comment: Just round the output to two places.

Comment: If you need to output it to the console or to a file then just convert to a `double` as usual then use `std::setprecision` on the stream you are using for the required data precision.

Comment: Do you want round, floor or ceil?

Comment: "outcome was not good" is rather unclear problem description...

Comment: Note that double is binary number. There will be rounding errors when converting to/from base-10 decimal numbers. This is unavoidable. You can't make double have 2 base-10 decimal places. But when you *print* (or convert to string) a double, at that point you can round the result to two decimal places. And for your current problem, double has so much precision, that rounding errors will not become visible "ever".

Comment: How about, truncate the string after the 2nd place of dot's digit, then convert to double the new truncated string.

Comment: What imeant by "the outcome was no good" was that i got a string "79.95"' and after turning it to a double i got  79.950000, and what i want to have is just 79.95, is there any way to do that?